# Register multiple content URI in a single ContentObserver

Tags: android

I am tracking the browser link. So, I am using the `ContentObserver` that I am registering in the `ContentObserver`.

So I have to here register multiple URI in a single `ContentObserver`.

Is this good idea to register multiple URI in a single ContentObserver Or any thing would go wrong If I do like this ?

BlockURL.java

```
public class BlockURLObserver extends ContentObserver {
    private Context context;
    public BlockURLObserver(Context con) {
        super(null);
        context = con;
        context.getContentResolver().registerContentObserver(Uri.parse("content://com.android.chrome.browser/bookmarks"), true, this);
        context.getContentResolver().registerContentObserver(Browser.BOOKMARKS_URI, true, this);
    }
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I think, better create single content observer to listen multiple URI. Rather creating multiple observer..

Here am giving common explanation.

Registering multiple URI in single contentobserver is possible.
At same time, using URI you have differentiate the code in onChange().

```
    @Override
    public void onChange(boolean selfChange, Uri uri) {
        super.onChange(selfChange);
    }
```

this onChange(boolean selfChange, Uri uri) get execute from API 16 onwards. So that you can register multiple URI in single content observer.

```
    @Override
    public void onChange(boolean selfChange, Uri uri) {
        super.onChange(selfChange);
        if(uri.toString.equalsgetUrifor((BOOKMARKS_URI))) {
            //do your stuff
        }
        if(uri.toString.equals(getUrifor(SOMETHING_ELSE))) {
            //...
        }
    }
```